# Use an input value along with a def function

Tags: python, function, input

i'm a begginer at phyton, and i am trying to create a function that indicates if is true or false if an even number is true or false.

This function is already working, but now i am trying to pass the function with a value given through the input function.

This is my code:

```
def isprime (value):
    
    value=int(input("Enter a number: "))
    
    if value < 2:
        return False
    else:
        for count in range (2, value):
            if value % count == 0:
                return False
            
        return True
            
isprime ()
```

When i run isprime () i get the following error message

TypeError: isprime() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Please, note that if i don't put the input part and i run the funcion like isprime (3) my output is TRUE.

Can you please help me to let me know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: It happens because function `isprime()` *requires positional argument `value`*.

Comment: You aren't passing the argument `value` to `isprime`. It doesn't need to have any arguments defined at all though. So just change the definition to `def isprime():` instead of `def isprime (value):`. If you wanted to keep the `value` argument, you'd have to pass user input to the function, like `isprime(int(input("Enter a number: ")))`

Comment: It is utterly pointless for `isprime()` to take the `value` parameter, since you overwrite it on the very first line of the function.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to have your functions manage input and output. Just remove the `value = int...` from your function, and call it with `n = int(input('...')) ; isprime(n)`. More generally, I would recommend that your read more existing code and study some good tutorial to find example of basic good practices.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is you need to pass the value to make the code work. However, you are taking the input inside the function. Therefore, you need to take the input outside the function.

```
value = int(input("Enter a number: "))
isprime(value)
```

Comment: I think the code might also be clarified (for beginners) by naming the function's parameter something different than the variable that's being passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the function with an argument *int(input("Enter a number: "))*, so your code might be :

```
def isprime(value):
    if value < 2:
        return False
    else:
        for count in range (2, value):
            if value % count == 0:
                return False
        return True
            
isprime(int(input("Enter a number: ")))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your function require one parameter but you don't give it.
Try this:

```
def isprime (value):
    
    if value < 2:
        return False
    else:
        for count in range (2, value):
            if value % count == 0:
                return False
            
        return True

value = int(input("Enter a number: "))
isprime (value)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're defining a required input to the function, but over-writing it with input from stdin. So do you want to use the input to the function or discard it ? In case you want to keep the input to the function optional, try

```
def isprime (value = None):
    
    if value is None:
        value=int(input("Enter a number: "))
    
    if value < 2:
        return False
    else:
        for count in range (2, value):
            if value % count == 0:
                return False
            
        return True
```

"None" is similar to a "null" value in python. NoneType in Python is a data type that simply shows that an object has no value/has a value of None. By setting `value = None` you're allowing for an optional input.

In this case if you execute `isprime()` it will ask the user for an input because value = None. If you execute `isprime(some_integer)` it will use value = some_integer.

Btw, if you want to check if a number is prime or not there is a more elegant way to do using **recursion**.